# Flutter build iOS FAILED

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

I build a new flutter project from VSCode, and run on iOS simulator (iphone 11), it shows:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           11.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    error: unable to spawn process (No such file or directory) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: unable to spawn process (No such file or directory) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps.

1. Open your Flutter project folder, in my case - **helloflutter** find the **iOS** folder and open that folder
2. Inside the "iOS" folder open **Rinner.xcworkspace** in your Xcode IDE
   [image]
3. Once Xcode open go to **Signin & Capabilities** (fallow the sequence to reach Signin & Capabilities from below image)
4. **Uncheck** checkbox that **Automatically manage signing** from **Signin & Capabilities**

[image]

5. Save the changes, close Xcode, and run the Flutter code once again.