# Build iOS Failed - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter, I have project my client want me to extract .ipa file and upload it.
I made provisioning profile and all setup is done.

I run command `flutter doctor -v`

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.21.0-9.2.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E266, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.21.0-9.2.pre at /Users/user/Documents/flutter
    • Framework revision 81a45ec2e5 (2 weeks ago), 2020-08-27 14:14:33 -0700
    • Engine revision 20a9531835
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-7.3.beta)

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.6, Build version 11E708
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

Scan[✓] Connected device (2 available)            
    • iPhone 8 (mobile)                   • 7484DAD5-9562-4A70-A83C-D8D4C378B35A • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-6 (simulator)
    • iPhone SE (2nd generation) (mobile) • 6A6DAEF0-D41D-4466-9815-826DF83ECB51 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-6 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

But when run `flutter build ios` this found this exception after xcode build done:

```
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "ProcessException: Process timed out:

  Command: /usr/bin/env xcrun xcodebuild -configuration Release -quiet
-workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner BUILD_DIR=/Users/user/Desktop/LadyCare/build/ios -sdk   iphoneos SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE=/var/folders/rt/fl3hxxg54zg57wrggxsbx42m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.ziHuHJ/flutter_build_log_pipe.uI1i3M/pipe_to_stdout FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
-showBuildSettings".
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065526/flutter-build-ios-failed

Comment: I tried this but not solved my problem the same exception shown

Comment: any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this, it might fix your problem

```
flutter clean && flutter run
```

The above command is basically implementing the command at the same time

```
>>> flutter clean
>>> flutter run
```

Comment: Great @Nehalosama