# Failed to build iOS app on vs code about try app on my phone

Tags: xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code

I have an error like this
https://share.getcloudapp.com/yAurZ0gl
(err:
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
error: "Runner" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
)
I want to try codes on my phone. When i try it on visual studio code, its give me an error.

I look this ([Flutter build iOS FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065526/flutter-build-ios-failed) ) but i couldn't solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 8 shows error that provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568005/xcode-8-shows-error-that-provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-signing-certificat)

Answer (score 0):

I read the error message on https://share.getcloudapp.com/yAurZ0gl, it says

`error: Failed to register bundle identifier, The app identifier "com.example.chatapp" cannot be registered because it is not available.`

Can you change the bundle identifier to a unique string and try again. Try using **"com.example.chatapp1"** or **"com.example.chatapp2"** or any other. And also make sure that you have `Provisioning Profile` set up in Xcode (The image is a guide).

[image]